# panic: dial tcp: lookup tcp/5432,: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found

Tags: postgresql, go, pgadmin-4

Can anyone help me with this error please?

```
panic: dial tcp: lookup tcp/5432,: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Dev/Digitalent/scalable-web-service-with-golang/go-sql/main.go:35 +0x23a
exit status 2
```

this is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    username = "postgres"
    password = "*********"
    dbName   = "db-go-sql"
)

var (
    db  *sql.DB
    err error
)

func main() {
    psqlURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d, user=%s, password=%s "+
        "dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, username, password, dbName)

    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", psqlURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connection to postgresql established")
}
```

It's about connecting my Go Lang code with PostgreSQL. I have checked the connection over and over, such as host, port, username, password, and dbname, and it's all good I think. But, this error always came up when I run the main program. I'm using Windows 11. Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess, but `The specified class was not found.` doesn't appear like a connection string issue.

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a bit more information if you wish anyone to help.

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into the question

Answer (score 2):

```
psqlURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d, user=%s, password=%s "+
        "dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, username, password, dbName)
```

You do have a `,` with the url string. Removing that comma should resolve your problem.

```
psqlURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s "+
        "dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, username, password, dbName)
```

This issue is originating from the [lookupIP](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.1:src/net/lookup_windows.go;l=98) method in the `lookup_windows.go` file, when it look for a port as `5432,`

```
var e error
for i := 0; i < dnsConf.attempts; i++ {
    e = syscall.GetAddrInfoW(name16p, nil, &hints, &result)
    if e == nil || e != _WSATRY_AGAIN || time.Since(start) > dnsConf.timeout {
        break
    }
}
if e != nil {
    err := winError("getaddrinfow", e)
    dnsError := &DNSError{Err: err.Error(), Name: name}
    if err == errNoSuchHost {
        dnsError.IsNotFound = true
    }
    return nil, dnsError
}
```